# Retrofit2 is parsing json inside json

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

I have class "News" where there are 2 fields: date, text. I do a request to API and have the answer:

```
{
  "payload": [
    {
      "id": "10024",
      "text": "Some text here",
      "publicationDate": {
        "milliseconds": 1513767691000
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "10004",
      "text": "Some text here too",
      "publicationDate": {
        "milliseconds": 1513684913000
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How I can parse field milliseconds with a retrofit. Can I just use:

```
@SerializedName("milliseconds")
private String milliseconds;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a class `PublicationDate` which has a field `milliseconds`. You can then access the `milliseconds` field by doing a `publicationDate.getMilliseconds()`.

In your `payload` class, you can annotate the publicationDate like this

```
@SerializedName("milliseconds")
private PublicationDate publicationDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make aa pojo class first like this

```
public class Pojo{
@SerializedName("payload")
@Expose
private List<Payload> payload = null;

public List<Payload> getPayload() {
return payload;
}

public void setPayload(List<Payload> payload) {
this.payload = payload;
}

public class Payload {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("text")
@Expose
private String text;
@SerializedName("publicationDate")
@Expose
private PublicationDate publicationDate;

public String getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getText() {
return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
this.text = text;
}

public PublicationDate getPublicationDate() {
return publicationDate;
}

public void setPublicationDate(PublicationDate publicationDate) {
this.publicationDate = publicationDate;
}

}
public class PublicationDate {

@SerializedName("milliseconds")
@Expose
private Integer milliseconds;

public Integer getMilliseconds() {
return milliseconds;
}

public void setMilliseconds(Integer milliseconds) {
this.milliseconds = milliseconds;
}

}
}
```

Now you can use the gson library for parsing data from the JSON response to directly this POJO class and then you can get the data for milliseconds from this from your pojo's subclass payload.

```
@SerializedName("milliseconds")
private PublicationDate publicationDate;
```

If need any other help for the same then please comment below.